# chrome app keeping sending tcp data sockets crashes after 20 hours

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I write a chrome app which sends 10,000,000 bytes using tcp socket each time and does this once an hour.

But after 20 hours, the chrome app crashes.

we have tried many times and it crashes approximately 20 hours later.

i donot know why.

Answer (score 1):

I'll ask the most obvious question....

Are you just using one socket, or are you creating a new socket each time?

If so, are you closing the socket when you're finished with it?

You need to be calling something like this...

```
 chrome.sockets.tcp.close(socketId, function() {
                             if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                                console.log('Failed to close socket ' + socketId);
                             } else {
                                  console.log('closed socket ' + socketId); 
                             }
                          });
```

Comment: yes, i am just using one socket all the time.thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem.

it is not caused by chrome.sockets.tcp socket api, but a third lib I have used!

the third lib consumes too much CPU and RAM resources.